# Complete the line - passive voice

Tags: verbs, passive-voice, active-voice

I have a homework, I have to complete the text and there is a sentence

> She still ________ to be a Russian hero.

I have to add the word CONSIDER in correct form. I thought it's *She is still considered....*
but I cannot change the order of the words, so I have no idea what to do. Thanks for helping me

[image: woman in space]

Comment: I have seen usages along the lines of "She still considers to be ...", but they usually appear to be written by folks who are not from Britain or the US.

Comment: Perhaps there was a transcription error, and the first word should be spelled "She's". The pronunciation of the first two words wouldn't change, but it would make the homework exercise a lot easier.

Comment: The image is too small to be able to read anything. Please consider replacing it with a larger image or just deleting it.

Comment: She still was considered to be a Russian hero.

Answer (score 9):

"She still is considered to be..." doesn't sound incorrect, although the word order you had suggested sounds more natural.

Answer (score 7):

The usual place for an adverb like *still* is after the first auxiliary verb, so your feeling is correct.

However, adverbs can go in many places, and right before the verb phrase is also OK, if perhaps not as common.

Probably this is about the necessities for making tests rather than English grammar. If the test constructor hadn't put the *still* before the blank, they'd have had to put in two blanks, and that would give away the answer.

So, C- to the test designer, and A for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right. The sentence should be like 'She *is* still *considered* to be a Russian hero.'

Another form would be She still *considers herself* to be a Russian hero.
This will not work her but will give you an idea of other uses.

They are likely looking for; 'She  still *is considered* to be a Russian hero.'
This is a bit stilted, awkward but not actually incorrect.
Try that and promise you will keep working hard.